# How to calculate the length $AH$?

Tags: geometry, triangles

We have a triangle $ABC$ and the heights $AD$ and $BE$ that intersect in $H$.

The following length are given: $$AB=12, \ BD=4, EC=  8, \ AE=6$$ How can we calculate $AH$ ?

Does the orthocenter divide a length by a specific ratio?

Comment: Are you looking for solution which is allowed to use sin, cos, etc. or a more elementary one? In general the orthocenter does not divide the altitudes in a specific ratio.

Comment: To use the sin and cos we have to calculate first the angles, right? Do we do that using the cosine rule? @peter.petrov

Comment: No, even simpler, you can just use the definitions of sin, cos (in the right-angled triangles which show up on the plot).

Comment: Do you know Menelaus' Theorem?

Comment: Ok, and if I found the angles, which formula do we use for the calculation of $AH$ ? @peter.petrov

Comment: Try deriving $AH=2R\cos(A)$ where $R$ is the circumradius of the triangle, by these right angled triangles in the plot and sine rule.

Comment: I am not sure yet. Still looking... Do you know Menelaus' Theorem?

Comment: Yes! But do we get at the formula $AH$ ? @LearningMathematics

Comment: Yes, I know that theorem but I am not sure how to apply that here @peter.petrov

Comment: Could you give me a hint? @peter.petrov

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, let me write something up.

Answer (score 3):

To prove: $AH=2R\cos(A)$ (symbols have their usual meanings in a triangle)

Follow $$AH = \dfrac{AE}{\cos(\angle HAE)} \ \left(from \ right-angled \ \Delta HAE\right)\\= \dfrac{AE}{\cos(\angle DAC)}=\dfrac{AE}{\cos(90^{\circ}-C)}=\dfrac{AE}{\sin(C)}$$

and $AE=AB\cos(A)$ (from right angled $\Delta ABE$)

so $$AH = \dfrac{AB\cos(A)}{\sin(C)} = \dfrac{c}{\sin(C)}\cos(A) = 2R\cos(A) \ \left(by \ sine \ rule\right)$$

Knowing $AH = 2R\cos(A) = \dfrac{b}{\sin(B)}\cos(A)$ (by sine rule)

Find $b=CA=CE+EA=14$, $\sin(B)=\dfrac{AD}{AB}=\dfrac{8\sqrt{2}}{12}=\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}3$ from the right angled $\Delta ABD$ and $\cos(A)=\dfrac{AE}{AB}=\dfrac12$ from the right angled $\Delta ABE$.

Answer (score 3):

Construction of $\triangle ABC$
based on given data is impossible,
since condition $|EC|=8,\ |AE|=6$
contradicts the other data in this construction.

[image]

However, triangle $ABC$ can be constructed
given three lengths
$|AB|=12=c,\ |BD|=4,\ |AC|=8+6=14=b$
as follows:

1. Side $AB$.
2. Circle $\Omega_B(B,|BD|)$.
3. Point $C_m=(A+B)/2$.
4. Circle $\Omega_{C_m}(C_m,\tfrac12\,|AB|)$.
5. Point $D=\Omega_{C_m} \cap \Omega_B$.
6. Line $\mathcal{L}_{BD}=BD$
7. Circle $\Omega_A(A,|AC|)$.
8. Point $C=\Omega_A \cap \mathcal{L}_{BD}$.
9. Point $E_1=\Omega_{C_m} \cap \mathcal{L}_{AC}$.
10. Point $H=\mathcal{L}_{AD}\cap \mathcal{L}_{BE_1}$

The foot of the other height is named $E_1$ fo avoid confusion
with the contradictory point $E$, mentioned in the OP.

\begin{align}
\triangle ABD:\quad
|AD|&=
\sqrt{|AB|^2-|BD|^2}
=8\sqrt2
,\\
\triangle ADC:\quad
|CD|&=
\sqrt{|AC|^2-|AD|^2}
=2\sqrt{17}
,\\
|BC|=a&=|BD|+|CD|=
4+2\sqrt{17}
.
\end{align}

Given $a,b,c$, we can find
the area $S$ and the circumradius $R$ of $\triangle ABC$
as

\begin{align}
S&=\tfrac12\,|AD|\cdot|BC|
=4\sqrt2\,(4+2\sqrt{17})
,\\
R&=\frac{abc}{4S}
=\frac{21\sqrt2}4
.
\end{align}

Finally, using that in any triangle
$ABC$ these relations hold true:

\begin{align}
a^2+|AH|&=b^2+|BH|^2=c^2+|CH|^2
=4R^2
,
\end{align}

the answer therefore is
\begin{align}
|AH|&=
4R^2-a^2
=\tfrac{\sqrt2}2\,(16-\sqrt{17})
\approx 8.398
.
\end{align}

Note that in this construction
the value of the distance from $C$
to the foot of the height from $B$
is clearly dictated
by the power of the point $C$
wrt $\Omega_{C_m}$

\begin{align}
|CE_1|&=\frac{|CD|\cdot|BC|}{|AC|}
=\tfrac27\,(17+2\sqrt{17})
\approx7.2132
\mathbf{\ \ne 8=|EC|}
,\quad\text{given in OP}
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution.

I had a small calculation mistake in the previous solution which I posted.

[image: p4]

Comment: That's the same as what I got using Menelau's Theorem. But it differs from Fawkes7794d3 answer, which I think is also right. I think the triangle has contradicting lengths.

Comment: Does this mean that with the given lengths it cannot be a triangle? @LearningMathematics

Comment: Yes, knowing the length of $AB$, $AE$, $EC$ and $BE$ is perpendicular to $AC$ already fix the whole triangle. I am still not able to find the length of $BD$ but it seems that it is not $4$

Comment: @Learning Mathematics, you're correct. I've uploaded the images of possible triangles in my answer but none matches with that of OP's question.

Comment: I missed it on a first viewing, I tried this answer, the calculations are alright, both peter.petrov and I have valid methods and correct calculations but different answers.  As noted by @SarGe , a triangle with the given lengths is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a scaled sketch of the problem in Geogebra by assuming the segments $AB, \, AE$ and $CE$ to be true and then finding the length of segment $BD$ for cross validation. Two such triangles are possible and I think there might be some error in your values else the answer is "No such triangle is possible". Also, let me know if I'm wrong.

[image]
[image]